# How to handle git gc fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/HEAD error?

Tags: git, git-remote, git-fetch, git-gc

I randomly hit this today while trying to run Git *garbage collect*:

```
$ git gc
fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
error: failed to run repack
```

How do I deal with this?

Answer (score 367):

I don't understand the ramifications of this, but as suggested [in this thread](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-git/2015-November/000061.html), when I encountered this I just did

```
$ mv .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD /tmp
```

(keeping it around just in case) and then

```
$ git gc
```

worked without complaining; I haven't run into any problems.

Comment: It worked for me and I think I got into this problem because I changed the default branch from `master` to another one called `develop`. Days before I change it back from `develop` to `master` and **I deleted the old default branch `develop`**, but in my working directory, the file `.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` was still pointing to `refs/remotes/origin/develop` which no longer exists. **In this situation** removing the file did work.

Comment: `git prune` worked for me, a way to delete data that has accumulated in Git but is not being referenced by anything useful.

Comment: Executing them solved my problem:
`$ mv .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD /tmp`
`$ git gc`
`git prune`

Comment: I suspect the best way would be @WilQu's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49944297/660339). Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: removing those file out of .git folder, than `git gc` worked for me

Comment: @Ryan you should check if this work for you, for me solved the problem.

Comment: In my case `git gc` showed several files as `fatal: bad object ...`. I moved each of them away into `/tmp`. Then, `git gc` worked and all was ok.

Comment: I got `mv: cannot stat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD: No such file or directory`

Comment: In my case, this happened because of Dropbox adding files like `index (xyz's conflicted copy 2022-06-25)` and `ORIG_HEAD (xyz's conflicted copy 2022-06-25)` etc. to the `.git` folder and subfolders in `.git/refs/`. Removing those and running `git gc` seem to have worked.

Comment: This also worked for non HEAD ref errors. (you just have to move the correct branch name to some other folder)

Comment: In my case, I was getting this error even after the branch this error was attached to had been deleted. I ended up just deleting the ref fil and doing a git prune, and it worked.

Comment: I get: mv: cannot stat '.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD': No such file or directory

Answer (score 198):

After seeing Trenton’s answer, I looked at my `.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` and saw that it was also pointing to an old branch that is now deleted.

But instead of editing the file myself, I tried Ryan’s solution:

```
git remote set-head origin --auto
```

It automatically set the file to the new branch, and `git gc` worked fine after that.

Comment: Yep, this works for me - as I was in the exact same scenario. `git remote set-head $REMOTE --auto` in my case, $REMOTE is the remote alias, not the default "origin", because I have multiple remotes setup.

Comment: this worked for me with git version 2.33.0

Comment: The error also instructed "Please correct the root cause and remove .git/gc.log".  This solution worked for me, only after removing that file.

Answer (score 122):

The problem that I ran into (which is the same problem that @Stavarengo mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145151/how-to-handle-git-gc-fatal-bad-object-refs-remotes-origin-head-error-failed-to#comment77981949_38192799) above) is that the default remote branch (`develop` in my case) had been deleted, but was still referenced in `.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`.

Opening `.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` in my editor showed this:

```
ref: refs/remotes/origin/develop
```

I *carefully* edited it to point at my new default branch and all was well:

```
ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
```

The clue that tipped me off was that running `git prune` showed this error:

```
> git prune
warning: symbolic ref is dangling: refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
```

Comment: That was my fix as well

Comment: This was my exact solution. Our team recently changed from using a default branch develop to master as well

Comment: I had to run `git gc` after this to get everything working again but this fixed it!

Comment: this fixed my issue as well :)))) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 87):

Thank god I found this
https://makandracards.com/chris-4/54101-fixing-a-git-repo

```
fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
error: failed to run repack
```

This may happen if upstream branches have been removed and your origin is pointing to it. You can confirm this by running:

`cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`

If it is pointing to a branch that doesn't exist, running:

`git remote set-head origin --auto`

followed by

`git gc`

will fix it

Comment: Very helpful, thanks.
This is a common issue when switching the head branch from `master` to `main`, as seen lately with many projects due to removing non inclusive terminology

Comment: `git remote set-head origin --auto && git gc` for convenient copy-paste in one go :)

Answer (score 30):

Looks like your symbolic-refs might be broken...
Try the replacing it with your default branch like this:
For example, my default branch is **master**

```
$ git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/master
$ git fetch --prune
$ git gc
```

That should fix it.

Comment: I just did nearly this and it worked. Here's what I actually ran


`git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/master;
git fetch --prune;
git prune;
git gc;`

Answer (score 9):

I hit this error because the default branch was changed from `master` to `main`.
I used a mix of info given by a few of the answers above to resolve it:

```sh
cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
```

Returned:

```sh
ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
```

To fix it, I ran:

```sh
git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/main
```

I ran this again to double-check:

```sh
cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
```

Which returned:

```sh
ref: refs/remotes/origin/main
```

Then `git gc` and `git prune` worked just fine.

---

To see what happens I also tried:

```sh
git remote set-head origin --auto
```

Which returned:

```sh
origin/HEAD set to main
```

And it really solves the problem by identifying the ref automatically.

Answer (score 8):

```
git update-ref -d [wrong reference here]
```

This will fix this issue.

For above issue use following code:

```
git update-ref -d 'refs/remotes/origin/HEAD'
```

In case you are getting error with .git like below:

```
error: bad ref for .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/Dec/session-dynatrace-logs 6
```

You can copy the path starting from refs like below:

```
git update-ref -d 'refs/remotes/origin/Dec/session-dynatrace-logs 6'
```

Comment: This fixes error *cannot update the ref 'refs/remotes/origin/mybranch': unable to create directory for '.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/mybranch': No such file or directory*

Comment: This gives me `error: refusing to update ref with bad name '.git/logs/HEAD 2'`.

Comment: make sure the path is correct

Answer (score 7):

```
rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD

git gc
```

Comment: this is simple and it worked for me after trying out different things.

Answer (score 4):

If someone is getting this error

```
fatal: bad object refs/stash 2
error: https://github.com/Username/repository.git did not send all necessary objects
```

this is how I fixed

```
mv .git/refs/stash\ 2 /tmp
git gc
```

Answer (score 3):

The above solution partially worked for me because my folder had the "desktop.ini" files everywhere in the repository as it is hosted on Google Drive, including the “.git” folders where Git was storing its own data. Git expected every file in that folder to contain Git data, not Google Drive data, and it choked trying to interpret the desktop.ini file contents.
To avoid this, make sure to include `desktop.ini` in `.gitignore`

I first deleted these files using a batch command on windows as follows:

1. create a "delete.bat" file in the repository and add the following code to it

   `del /s /q /f /a ".\desktop.ini"`
2. Open `cmd` and open the current folder
3. run `delete.bat` by simply calling it in `cmd`

Now you should be able to run
`git remote set-head origin --auto`

followed by `git gc`

Comment: Why is git not smart enough to just ignore these desktop.ini files?

Comment: I guess, we'd have to ask git.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a branch that causes this error. You need to do the following things:

Go to .git and remove the branch that makes the error.

I had this error:

```
fatal: bad object refs/heads/extract_false_neg
```

I removed files with the name 'extract_false_neg' inside .git/ref/tags and ./git/ref/head.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using git worktrees, make sure you're doing a

```
git worktree prune
```

before running

```
git gc
```

I had a worktree get corrupted and this seemed to do the trick after removing the corrupted worktree. `git prune` by itself didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this for me was working in a compressed folder in Windows.  When the folder was uncompressed, it corrupted the pack files, cascading other odd issues, such as not being able to prune nonexistent branches.

The only fix was to wipe out the working directory and clone the repo remote(s) again. Luckily, I could still push and pull updates to ensure nothing was lost.  All is well now.

Answer (score 1):

My problem occurred with a specific branch.

Apparently the reference file for branch was corrupted. I fixed it like that.

> git checkout main
>
> // I removed the file .git\refs\heads\branch_xpto
>
> git pull
>
> git checkout branch_xpto

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, when I tried to pull from the origin branch, I got the following error:

```
fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/account
```

The solutions above didn't work for me for some reason. Kept getting this error

```
mv: cannot stat '.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD': No such file or directory
```

And running `git gc` gave this error:

```js
error: bad ref for .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/account
fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/account
fatal: failed to run repack
```

In my situation, the remote branch was pointing to a branch that didn't exist.

What fixed it for me was deleting the branch

```
git branch -D account
```

and also deleting it from `.git/refs/remotes/origin/account`

Everything working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to get into the folder itself in my pc cause I kept getting the error

```
No such file or directory
```

whenever I run

```
mv .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD /tmp 

$ git gc git prune
```

After opening the hidden files, you can do this by pressing
**cmd + shift + .** on Mac or [Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-97fbc472-c603-9d90-91d0-1166d1d9f4b5) then **ref > remote > origin** and delete the unnecessary files

Answer (score 0):

In my I just deleted that particular `refs`: `refs/heads/feat/implement-games`. After that, I was already able to `git pull origin master`

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure how this occurs, but it seems that its being caused due to duplicates.

What worked for me was manually deleting duplicates. I navigated to each of the folders and manually removed the duplicates.

I had the below issue
bad object refs/tags/v1.0.1 2

1. Open the repo in a terminal
2. Navigate to /tags using the cd command
3. Run the ls command to verify the duplicate exists i.e. v1.0.1 2
4. Run the rm command to remove the duplicate -> rm v1.0.1\ 2 (\ to handle the space)

Then try to git gc again. In my case, I had more duplicates in diff locations that I had to manually delete in the same manner, but once all were removed - everything work normally.

I hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

for me, the problem was occurring with the push from VS Code. I did `git push` manually in the terminal. it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me a deleted branch on origin was creating that error.

Edited:  `.git\info\refs` And removed the line with the branch causing this error, in my case a feature branch that was pushed to origin, but did not go trough and somehow deleted on origin.

Then run  `git fetch --prune` and then  `git gc`

Answer (score 0):

I search "fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/master" and flowing the link to this stackoverflow question to find answer.

- **My situatioin**

1. `git status`

```
zsh ❯ git status
On branch master
Your branch is based on 'origin/master', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)
```

2. after I execute `git branch --unset-upstream`, I could `git pull`, but got this error

```
Unpacking objects: 100% (19/19), 6.82 KiB | 6.82 MiB/s, done.
fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/master
error: https://github.com/lapce/lapce-plugin-rust did not send all necessary objects
```

- **Try to find solution**

follow the fatal massage,

1. `cat .git/refs/heads/master`, got a COMMIT-HASH
2. `cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`, got `ref: refs/remotes/origin/master`
3. `cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/master`, it was empty

maybe the file `.git/refs/remotes/origin/master` was the problem.

4. `rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/master`, `git pull` again, I got,

```
   a9c3764..02d3a76  master     -> origin/master
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

5. OK, **set-upstream** back

```
zsh ❯ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
branch 'master' set up to track 'origin/master'.
```

6. try `git pull`

```
zsh > git pull
Updating a9c3764..02d3a76
Fast-forward
 .gitignore      |   2 ++
 Cargo.lock      |  55 +++++++++++++++++++------------------------------------
 Cargo.toml      |   3 +--
 README.md       |   2 ++
 src/main.rs     |  89 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++----------------------------
 
...

 8 files changed, 88 insertions(+), 67 deletions(-)
```

It looked fine.

7. `cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/master`, `cat .git/refs/heads/master`, got the same COMMIT-HASH.

- **So, Finally**

In my case, the HEAD COMMIT-HASH in the file **.git/refs/remotes/origin/master** was empty( git told u **the upstream is gone**), somehow. Delete the file, and `git pull` again to rebuild it, follow **git advise message** after every git command's feedback, would probably get thing done.

Answer (score 0):

Check, if any **files are corrupted**:

```
git fsck --full
```

If so, run:

```
git prune
git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the entire project and pulled it back

Comment: That sounds like a pretty drastic solution

Answer (score 0):

Have no idea how did I corrupt it so badly, but nothing from that branch helps me. I finish with next solution:

1. clone project into separate folder
2. (optional) - switch to related branch
3. copy-paste .git folder from newly created project into original
4. git status and git add commands to prepare commit