# Git bad ref & bad object issues

Tags: git

Getting error below when executing command like `git pull` or `git fetch`, how to fix those issues:
BTW, ranch `new-lg` and `features_empty_check` could be deleted, they are not used anymore.

```
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
error: bad ref for .git/logs/refs/heads/new-lg
fatal: bad object refs/heads/features_empty_check
fatal: failed to run repack
```

Comment: You could delete those refs. Or try `git fsck`. Or just clone from the remote to get a fresh copy that works.

Comment: @matt Thanks! Delete those refs can solve the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git unable to pull remote changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48836735/git-unable-to-pull-remote-changes)

Comment: @GinoMempin i think so