# How to solve error bad object refs/heads/main (1) after running git pull

Tags: r, git, github, rstudio, git-pull

How can I solve this error when I run `git pull` in Terminal on a Mac?

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 115, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (115/115), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (66/66), done.
remote: Total 104 (delta 71), reused 63 (delta 30), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (104/104), 3.92 MiB | 3.16 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (71/71), completed with 9 local objects.
fatal: bad object refs/heads/main (1)
error: https://github.com/[...domain name...]/website.git did not send all necessary objects
```

The background is that I have a website that usually works with no problem. I created it in RStudio and sync it with github. Netlify goes from there. Here is what the setup is based on: https://www.apreshill.com/blog/2020-12-new-year-new-blogdown/.

After I make changes in RStudio, from within RStudio, I can usually just commit and then push the changes. But this time, it says this:

```
 ! [rejected]        HEAD -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/[domain name]/website.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again
```

So I go to Terminal and change the working directory to where the files are stored and run `git pull`. I then get the `fatal: bad object refs/heads/main (1)` error mentioned above. Based on [How to handle git gc fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/HEAD error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145151/how-to-handle-git-gc-fatal-bad-object-refs-remotes-origin-head-error), I tried `git gc` and get this error:

```
error: bad ref for .git/logs/HEAD (1)
error: bad ref for .git/logs/refs/heads/main (1)
fatal: bad object refs/heads/main (1)
fatal: failed to run repack
```

I also tried `git remote set-head origin --auto` and then `git gc` and get the same error as directly above.

If I run `cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`, it says: `refs/remotes/origin/main`.

Finally, I tried `git reset --hard` before `git pull` and this gives me the original error.

I am not sure what to do at this point. I am totally fine to get everything from the remote server and redo my local changes.

Comment: Have you looked inside the `.git/refs/heads/main` file?

Comment: That file does not exist locally. But the `.git/refs/heads/main (1)` file contains only a single line. It is a long string of letters and numbers.

Comment: The `(1)` suffix in the filename is strange. Maybe it was added accidentally by OS. Try to delete it from the filename.

Comment: Ah - I deleted ` (1)`, did `git reset --hard HEAD`, then `git pull`, and it all works now! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your repository a file named `.git/refs/heads/main (1)` exists, which also means that local branch `main (1)` exists. The name contains a space which is not allowed in branch names (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3651867/14967413)), which is probably the cause of error.

The  `(1)` suffix probably emerged accidentally. Try to remove it from file names first and then run other operations.

Comment: Probably what happened is that for some reason the `main (1)` file got created by Google Drive.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me as well.

Comment: Yeah, for me this keeps happening with new Dropbox set-up for some reason, conflicting heads.