# getting this error message when I am trying to running fetch from my github desktop

Tags: git

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 4, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), 1.51 KiB | 771.00 KiB/s, done.
fatal: bad object refs/stash 2
error: https://github.com/Rezaavoor/Birdr.git did not send all necessary objects
```

I removed some files from repository, and then I have tried to fetch from github and this what I encountred

Comment: If you have unstaged changes, you may wish to backup the directory and clone again.  Alternately, you may have success deleting and re-adding your `origin`.  Here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37145151/3196753